# how to change this xpath expression to css for selenium

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I've been using xpath a lot recently.

Now I'm going to start using css a lot, based on advice I've received.

How would I take an xpath expression like

```
//tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a@href
```

and convert it to css?

I tried

```
tr.td:contains('6 Day'):nth(1) > td:nth(3) > a[href]
```

but I got an error

Answer (score 1):

Minor mistake, I should have had:

```
tr td:contains('6 Day'):nth(1) > td:nth(3) > a[href]
```